# GNU Crypto Encrypt returns blank string

Tags: java, encryption

I'm using GNU Crypto library to encrypt simple strings. I believe I have followed to documentation correctly, but the problem is that it just returns an blank string (in this case 5 characters) of spaces. I'm not sure whether I miss coded it or if its some encoding issue. I hope its not something embarrassingly simple.

```
import gnu.crypto.cipher.CipherFactory;
import gnu.crypto.cipher.IBlockCipher;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FTNSAMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "Apple";
    String key = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";

    byte[] temp = Encrypt(data.getBytes(), key.getBytes(), "AES");
    System.out.println(new String(temp));
}

public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, String algorithm) throws Exception {
    byte[] output = new byte[input.length];

    IBlockCipher cipher = CipherFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    Map attributes = new HashMap();

    attributes.put(IBlockCipher.CIPHER_BLOCK_SIZE, 16);
    attributes.put(IBlockCipher.KEY_MATERIAL, key);
    cipher.init(attributes);

    int bs = cipher.currentBlockSize();
    for (int i = 0; i + bs < input.length; i += bs) {
        cipher.encryptBlock(input, i, output, i);
    }
    return output;
}

}
```

Comment: `byte[]` probably contains unprintable characters that you try to print. You should instead encode the result as Base64 or Hex in order to look at it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I tried converting the result to hexadecimal but all I got was "0000000000".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU Crypto documentation have the following to say about the `void encryptBlock(..)` methode:

> Encrypts a block of bytes from plaintext starting at inOffset, storing
>   the encrypted bytes in ciphertext, starting at outOffset. It is up to
>   the programmer to ensure that there is at least one full block in
>   plaintext from inOffset and space for one full block in ciphertext
>   from outOffset. A java.lang.IllegalStateException will be thrown if
>   the cipher has not been initialized.

Your input:

```
String data = "Apple";
```

Is not a full datablock as AES needs data in blocks of **16 bytes**. Also, your output buffer is also too short.

For starters, try encrypting with an input that ends up as 16 bytes like:

```
String data = "Apple56789abcdef";
```

Comment: To encrypt the last block, which for this example is the only block, also use `<=` not `<` i..e `for (i=0; i+bs <= input.length; i+=bs) ...`. Once the input is a multiple of the blocksize, making the output the same size as the input should be okay. But note that encrypting each block separately, called ECB mode, in practice allows encryption to be broken; search crypto.SE and security.SE for numerous questions on why you should not use ECB mode, or just check the (in)famous ECB penguin at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation .